# Как организовать навигацию по приложению?

Tags: java, android

Представим что у нас есть 3 Activity:

1. ProfileActivity - отображает текст с имнем пользователя.
2. UserListActivity - отображает список имен пользователей. При нажатии на имя загружается ProfileActivity с его именем.
3. UserListTwoActivity - отображает список имен пользователей. При нажатии на имя загружается ProfileActivity с его именем.

В ProfileActivity можно попасть из двух других activity. Как назначать parent activity чтобы при нажатии на кнопку назад возвращаться на предыдущее activity?
Подобная навигация реализована во всех популярных клиентах для социальных сетей.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну во первых если вы не вызывали `finish()` у UserListActivity или UserListTwoActivity когда стартовали ProfileActivity, то по кнопке назад вернётся та с которой вы перешли на профиль. Во вторых я бы рекомендовал использовать для каждого экрана отдельный фрагмент, а не активити. Между фрагментами можно более гибко навигироваться. А активити я бы оставил только одну.

Comment: А вы не могли бы дать ссылку на документацию или пример по навигации с помощью фрагментов?

Comment: Вот более менее неплохая [статья](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/fragments.php). Ну и конечно же [офф документация](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/components/fragments.html). Рекомендую сразу использовать фрагменты из библиотеки совместимости, собственно даже сама студия сейчас при создании нового проекта с активити и фрагментом использует фрагменты из этой библиотеки.